# Django REST API's for models with Foreignkey's

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I want to Build an API with DRF to View the shopping cart. It works in the non API version but I get an error in the serializer that fields do not exist in the model.

models.py

```
class Product(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=False)
    cover_image = models.ImageField(upload_to='products/')
    summary = models.TextField()
    description = models.TextField()
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=6, decimal_places=2)
def __str__(self):
    return self.title

class Cart(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    order_date = models.DateField(null=True)
def __str__(self):
    return self.user.username

class Order(models.Model):
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product)
    cart = models.ForeignKey(Cart)
    quantity = models.IntegerField(default=1)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.product.title
```

views.py

```
def cartview(request):
    if request.user.is_authenticated():
        cart = Cart.objects.filter(user=request.user, active=True)
        orders = Order.objects.filter(cart=cart)
        total = 0
        count = 0
        for order in orders:
            total += (order.product.price * order.quantity)
            count += order.quantity
        context = {
            'total': total,
            'cart': orders,
            'count': count,
        }
        return render(request, 'store/cart.html', context)
    else:
        return redirect('index:index')
```

api/views.py

```
class CartAPIView(ListAPIView):
    permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated]
    serializer_class = CartSerializer

    def get_queryset(self, **kwargs):
        cart = Cart.objects.filter(user=self.request.user, active=True)
        orders = Order.objects.filter(cart=cart)
        total = 0
        count = 0
        for order in orders:
            total += (order.product.price * order.quantity)
            count += order.quantity
            context = {
                'total': total,
                'cart': orders,
                'count': count,
            }   
        return context
```

serializers.py

```
class CartSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Cart
        fields = [
                    'title',
                    'cover_image',
                    'summary',
                    'price',
                ]
```

I get this error **Field name `title` is not valid for model `Cart`.**

I get the items in the template view but not in the api view. so what is that i should be doing here?

Comment: Your Cart model does not have field named title and that's why it raises the error. Maybe you have an error and in the serializer class and instead of using model = Cart (in the Meta subclass) you should use model = Product. I think that will solve the problem

Comment: I see the get_queryset() method should be returning queryset object i guess.

Comment: This error is clear you are trying to serialize Cart model which does not have title attribute. You should rethink on the approach.
Also see http://www.apimonk.com/ for automating Web API development

Answer (score 0):

Your cart model has no field or method `Title`, but you've included it in your fields list.  You can only serialize fields or methods that exist on the model, or that you create explicit links to.

You get the product titles  in your template because you're passing back 
`orders = Order.objects.filter(cart=cart)`.  Your `Order` object string method, which is what you're displaying in the template is `return self.product.title` - so you're going from the order object, to the corresponding product (a join) and fetching the title attribute of that object.

To do the same in the serializer, you need to define a serializer for each object, and then nest them.

```
 class CartSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Cart
        fields = [
                    'title',
                    'cover_image',
                    'summary',
                    'price',
                ]

class ProductSerializer(ModelSerializer):
      class Meta:
           model = Product
      ...etc... 

class OrderSerializer(ModelSerializer):
     class Meta:
          model = Order
     product = ProductSerializer
     ...etc...
```

Comment: I did try that from (http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#nested-relationships) this link. Still get the same error.

Comment: Without seeing the rest of your serializers, it's hard to say what you've done.  But as provided, your CartSerializer is never going to work; you don't have that field.

Comment: Also, if you're getting the same error, then you haven't removed 'title' from your fields list.

Comment: Having just thrown this together in my own environment, this seems to work.  What have you changed?